# Can I change a site's content niche for SEO, or should I start a new site?

Tags: seo, content

I have website with technology related articles from 2-3 years ago.  Since then I added hosting related articles.

Now, I am thinking of changing the niche and writing articles about the top 10 phones, the best networking devices, etc.

The site is getting daily traffic of 300-400 visitors. Should I do it or start a new website for this niche? Wouldn't it be easier to rank on current site which already is an authoritative site?

Comment: How do phones and networking devices not fit under your stated umbrella of "technology"?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by authoritative like you have old domain, have social media profiles, verifies site on search console etc then good. Otherwise niche and authority site is misunderstood in the SEO world as clostenoc said.

Google use PageRank+TrustRank+ Page Expert Score and sum of many private algorithm to rank specific webpage (They don't rank based on site topic). **There is no any SEO disadvantages to add different kind of topic on website.**

Comment: Somewhat disagree because its not secret that is actually easier to rank a site that sticks to a particular topic, because they can become a authority for that niche and links gained are often more relevant.

Comment: I agree. Authority is rather misunderstood in the SEO world, however, it does exist. PR is a part of authority. So is domain trust. Add authorship, and semantic scores to denote expertise level, reading level, citations, and so on and so on, authority is a very real thing.

Comment: @closetnoc I know about Page Expert score from some patent and white paper, it will be great if you share some reference on authority as well.

Comment: Google does not really talk much about authority except in relation to authorship, however, the term has been used from the very beginning to describe PageRank and is part of the whole concept of what metrics signal that a page or site is an authority for any search query. That is at least what I have gleaned.

Comment: Your reply help me to learn better English (I don't know what mean of gleaned), and SEO as well. :D

Answer (score 0):

- This answer may not answer your question but I hope it gives some ideas.

Assuming that you are going to use the same domain for your new niche and you don't change any architecture / link flow , you don't have start a new website as the current website is already having some authority as a old domain.

Adding new topic may dilute the authority on site's authority to the topic as said by Simon, but not much. Win some..lose some. But if it not hard for you to create authority for the new niche, you can start new site.